# Python 3 raise TypeError, 'Time.milliseconds expects a datetime object

Tags: python, datetime, object, timestamp

I just upgraded my mac OS 10.9 environment to Python 3.3 and now when I run a Python lib script I get the following error:

raise TypeError, 'Time.milliseconds expects a date time object

Here's the isolated code that is apparently causing the error:

```
@classmethod
def to_unix(cls, timestamp):
    """ Wrapper over time module to produce Unix epoch time as a float """
    if not isinstance(timestamp, datetime.datetime):
        raise TypeError, 'Time.milliseconds expects a datetime object'
    base = time.mktime(timestamp.timetuple())
    return base
```

And here is the code in the entire section in which the above code resides:

```
@classmethod
def from_unix(cls, seconds, milliseconds = 0):
    """ Produce a full |datetime.datetime| object from a Unix timestamp """
    base = list(time.gmtime(seconds))[0:6]
    base.append(milliseconds * 1000) # microseconds
    return datetime.datetime(* base)

@classmethod
def to_unix(cls, timestamp):
    """ Wrapper over time module to produce Unix epoch time as a float """
    if not isinstance(timestamp, datetime.datetime):
        raise TypeError, 'Time.milliseconds expects a datetime object'
    base = time.mktime(timestamp.timetuple())
    return base

@classmethod
def milliseconds_offset(cls, timestamp, now = None):
    """ Offset time (in milliseconds) from a |datetime.datetime| object to now """
    if isinstance(timestamp, (int, float)):
        base = timestamp
    else:
        base = cls.to_unix(timestamp) 
        base = base + (timestamp.microsecond / 1000000)
    if now is None:
        now = time.time()
    return (now - base) * 1000
```

which is probably referencing one of these libs:

```
    import date time 
    import time
```

Any ideas? I didn't have this error prior to the upgrade so maybe there has been a redefinition of timestamp or datetime?

Thank you

Comment: You did not show the calling code. A traceback would be nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it has anything to do with that.

Instead, I think you are getting a `SyntaxError` because your syntax for `raise` is illegal in Python 3.x:

```
>>> raise TypeError, 'error'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    raise TypeError, 'error'
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Instead, it needs to be like this:

```
>>> raise TypeError('error')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: error
>>>
```

Here is a [reference](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3109/).

Comment: Thank you!!! That looks familiar. I will test it later today and approve the answer if it works.